# unable to run ansible against windows server 2022

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ansible, packer

[image]I am trying to run ansible in packer provisioner against windows server 2022. I am using this cis hardend role but i am not able to provide the packer initiated ec2 instance on which this playbook should run https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/Windows-2022-CIS/blob/devel/site.yml

My packer provisioner looks like this

```
  provisioner "ansible" {
    playbook_file = "../../roles/Windows-2022-CIS/site.yml"
    extra_arguments  = ["-e", "windows_instance_ip={{ .HTTPIP }}"]
  }
```

The `site.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
- hosts: windows_instance_ip
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
      - role: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
```

All i want is my ansible should run on packer initiated windows instance. Currently it's running on my github action runner ubuntu 22. If i put localhost it gives me error, if i put "all" it also gives me error, i am unable to dynamically provide private ip of packer initiated ec2 to site.yml file

After implementing the suggested comments, i am getting syntax error when running ansible-local provisioner. These are my files now

```
  provisioner "ansible-local" {
    playbook_file   = "../../roles/Windows-2022-CIS/site.yml"
  }
```

The `site.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  roles:
      - role: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
```

Comment: Could you accept the formatting fixes, and then expand your question adding the details on what exact errors do you encounter for all cases?

Comment: I noticed you use `windows_instance_ip` variable as a host name. It could probably work if you had `hosts: "{{ windows_instance_ip }}"` instead of `hosts: windows_instance_ip`. Alternatively, if you want to run Ansible **on** the target machine, you'll probably want to use [ansible-local](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/ansible/latest/components/provisioner/ansible-local) provisioner.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev i have now used ansible-local provisioner. My provisioner looks like this provisioner "ansible-local" {
    playbook_file   = "../../roles/Windows-2022-CIS/site.yml"
  }    and my site.yml file looks like this - hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  roles:
      - role: "{{ playbook_dir }}"  . The build starts with no errors, previously i used to get errors that host name not found in site.yml but now i dont see errors but i dont see ansible full play book run anyways. i have attached screenshot of recent error

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev i even used this "{{ windows_instance_ip }}" but the private ip of instance is not getting populated. In other words can you please give me an idea how can i run site.yml playbook using packer provisioned ec2 instance private ip. I want my playbook to run on windows instance. If i have a separate linux server and i hardcode private ip of windows, my playbook runs without any issue